# Group by SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

So I got this statement, which works fine:

```
SELECT   MAX(patient_history_date_bio) AS med_date, medication_name
FROM     biological
WHERE    patient_id = 12)
GROUP BY medication_name
```

But, I would like to have the corresponding medication_dose also. So I type this up

```
SELECT   MAX(patient_history_date_bio) AS med_date, medication_name, medication_dose
FROM     biological
WHERE    (patient_id = 12)
GROUP BY medication_name
```

But, it gives me an error saying:

> "coumn 'biological.medication_dose' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.".

So I try adding medication_dose to the GROUP BY clause, but then it gives me extra rows that I don't want.
I would like to get the latest row for each medication in my table. (The latest row is determined by the max function, getting the latest date).

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: It looks like the OP is using SQL Server.

Comment: the one that is used by visual studio 2008 coding in c#. I think it's sql server right?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/sql-fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95866/select-max-in-group, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/sql-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column, and many others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT b.medication_name,
       b.patient_history_date_bio AS med_date,
       b.medication_dose
  FROM BIOLOGICAL b
  JOIN (SELECT y.medication_name,
               MAX(y.patient_history_date_bio) AS max_date
          FROM BIOLOGICAL y
      GROUP BY y.medication_name) x ON x.medication_name = b.medication_name
                                   AND x.max_date = b.patient_history_date_bio
 WHERE b.patient_id = ?
```

Comment: +1 - just pipped me to the post. This is the correct (and medically safe!) answer as it will give the latest dosage, not the highest dosage that MAX() would give (which would not necessarily be the latest dose). My only addition would be, if there are multiple records with the same date - if that's the case, you'd need to use another field in addition to determine the latest (e.g. an IDENTITY field).

Comment: thx a lot man (even tho i have a little bit of trouble understanding your statement... no worries i'll figure it out). sorry for the late reply

Comment: hmmmm weird this doesn't seem to work.... it only gives me 2 rows, while it's supposed to give 3...

Comment: @jello: What does the data look like?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @jello: Post some example data, so I can try to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to, as one quick workaround, you can apply an aggregate function to your `medication_dose` such as `MAX(medication_dose)`.

However note that this is normally an indication that you are either building the query incorrectly, or that you need to refactor/normalize your database schema. In your case, it looks like you are tackling the query incorrectly. The correct approach should the one  suggested by [OMG Poinies in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349500/group-by-sql-statement/2349537#2349537).

You may be interested in checking out the following interesting article which describes the reasons behind this error:

- [But *WHY* Must That Column Be Contained in an Aggregate Function or the GROUP BY clause?](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/60261.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `max(medication_dose)` in your select.  `Group by` returns a result set that contains distinct values for fields in your group by clause, so apparently you have multiple records that have the same `medication_name`, but different doses, so you are getting two results.

By putting in `max(medication_dose)` it will return the maximum dose value for each `medication_name`. You can use any aggregate function on dose (max, min, avg, sum, etc.)