# Max (SQL-Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
BARCODE      | PRICE  | STARTDATE
007023819815 | 159000 | 2008-11-17 00:00:00.000
007023819815 | 319000 | 2009-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

How can I select so I can get the result like this:

```
BARCODE      | PRICE  | STARTDATE
007023819815 | 319000 | 2009-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

select by using **max date**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this answer to a similar question changing revision into startdate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95866/select-max-in-group

Comment: @rah.deex: I have reformatted your question, please have a look at the new version to learn about formatting (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Peter Lang: Thanks Mr. Peter.. I'm sory about it..

Comment: @DavGarcia: Thx Mr.DavGarcia..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 barcode, price, startdate
FROM TableName
ORDER BY startdate DESC
```

Or if there can be more than one rows.

```
SELECT barcode, price, startdate
FROM TableName A
WHERE startdate = (SELECT max(startdate) FROM TableName B WHERE B.barcode = A.barcode)
```

**UPDATE**
changed second query to view max values per barcode.

Comment: This will only select rows with the maximum start date, not the maximum start date per barcode

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to do that is using the analytic function `row_number`:

```
SELECT  barcode, price, startdate
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY barcode ORDER BY startdate DESC) as rn
        FROM    YourTable
        ) subquery
WHERE   rn = 1
```

If performance is an issue, check out some more complex options in [this blog post](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/30/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/).

Comment: I think, you are missing `DESC` next to `ORDER BY startdate`