# SQL Server query GROUP BY with Where

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have table `tblEvents` with columns `dEvent_Date, dEvent_Time, tEvent_Emp_Code_num`

I must group all dates and get all minimum time from each of them.

For example I wrote below query, but its nothing printed.

```sql
SELECT dEvent_Date, MIN(dEvent_Time) as minTime 
FROM tblEvents 
WHERE
     tEvent_Emp_Code_num = 26 AND dEvent_Date = 11/18/2010 
GROUP BY dEvent_Date
```

After that I tested below query, it works, but it prints all days, I need only specified date's data.

```sql
SELECT dEvent_Date, MIN(dEvent_Time) as minTime 
FROM tblEvents 
WHERE tEvent_Emp_Code_num = 26 GROUP BY dEvent_Date
```

Can you help me?

Comment: can u plz be more clear and precise ???

Comment: dEvent_Date = "11/18/2010" <string

Comment: Does query SELECT * FROM tblEvents WHERE tEvent_Emp_Code_num = 26 AND dEvent_Date = 11/18/2010 returns anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Find the max record per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657482/sql-find-the-max-record-per-group), also [Select max in Group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95866/select-max-in-group) and many, many others on this site alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same problem and i have used cast function in mysql where my query look like

```
CREATE VIEW v_a AS SELECT
  tblEvents .*,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dEvent_Date) AS 'year',
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dEvent_Date) AS 'month',
  DAYOFMONTH(dEvent_Date) AS 'day'
FROM tblEvents WHERE tEvent_Emp_Code_num = 26;
SELECT
  v.year,
  v.month,
  v.day,
  count(v.id)
FROM v_a AS v
GROUP BY v.year,v.month,v.day
```

for SQL SErver you may use  CONVERT Function

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 4) AS [DD.MM.YY]
```

or cast function

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

perhaps following post is more useful

[Get Date Only Function](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-date-only.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How is your Date stored in table? The default Date format of MySQL is: yyyy-mm-dd. Also you must enclose date in single quotes.

And you should search like:

where dEvent_Date = '2010/11/18'

if you are not specifying Date Format.

Answer (score 0):

if db is dql this the Formate to check the value In DB,,,,,

or else u,,,,
you have to convert the date value into '2010-11-18' like

```
$date   =   date('Y-m-d',strtotime(11/18/2010)); 

   dEvent_Date = $date
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for this case:

```
SELECT dEvent_Date, MIN(dEvent_Time) as minTime 
FROM   tblEvents 
WHERE  tEvent_Emp_Code_num = 26 
GROUP BY dEvent_Date
HAVING  CAST('2015/01/01 00:00:01' AS DATETIME) < dEvent_Date 
        AND dEvent_Date >  CAST('2015/05/05 00:00:01' AS DATETIME)
```

(Refrences) how to use the keyword having:

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx